# Django: Passing a csrf token through ajax to an UpdateView 405 method not found error

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, csrf, django-csrf

I am creating an FAQ app. In my article detail page I am attempting to implement a vote up system. The goal is to allow a user to vote up an article if they find it useful. I do not want the page to be refreshed when the user clicks the vote up button. I have chosen to use an Ajax call from the template along a url to an UpdateView.

Django needs a csrf token to be passed along. The problem I am encountering is a `405 (Method Not Allowed)` error. I have verified in my network setting in chrome dev that the csrf token is being generated and assigned in the http header. I think the issue may lay in the view but everything I have tried so far has come up short. Any direction would be helpful.

EDIT UPDATE:

I am using Django 1.10

**The Url:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from faq.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ironfaq/$', DashboardView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', SectionView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/(?P<topic_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<section_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="faq-article-detail"),
    url(r'^ironfaq/topic/create/$', TopicCreateView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/section/create/$', SectionCreateView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/(?P<topic_pk>\d+)/article/create/$', ArticleCreateView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/topic/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', TopicUpdateView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/section/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', SectionUpdateView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/article/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ArticleUpdateView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/topic/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', TopicDeleteView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/section/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', SectionDeleteView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/article/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ArticleDeleteView.as_view()),
    url(r'^ironfaq/article/vote/(?P<pk>\d+)$/', ArticleVoteView.as_view()),
]
```

**The Template Script:**

```
{% block scripts %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });


    function post_call(vote_data){
        var data = {vote_type: vote_data};
        var id = {{ object.id }};
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ironfaq/article/vote/"+id+"/",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
        }).done(function() {
           console.log("POST!"); 
        });
    }

    var vote_up = "vote_up";
    var vote_down = "vote_down";

    var thumbs_up = $('#thumbs_up');
    var thumbs_down = $('#thumbs_down');

    thumbs_up.on('click', function(){
        post_call(vote_up)
    });
    thumbs_down.on('click', function(){
        post_call(vote_down)
    });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**The View:**

```
class ArticleVoteView(UpdateView):
    model = Article
    fields = []

    def form_valid(self, form):
        article = form.save(commit=False)
        vote_type = self.request.POST.get('vote_type')

        if vote_type == 'vote_up':
            article.vote_up = article.vote_up + 1
            article.save()
        elif vote_down == 'vote_down':
            article.vote_down = article.vote_down + 1
            article.save()

        data = {'status': 'success', 'vote_type': vote_type, 'yes_count': article.vote_up, 
                'total_votes': article.total_votes()}

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Django does not like urls without trailing slash - start there as it may do some redirects. If that does not help you can always try to overload views `dispatch` method to see what kind of request is being built - use `pdb` in that method.

Comment: Are you sure that the url is being handled by that view? Please show your url patterns.

Comment: Have made the edit to show all urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your post request to `/ironfaq/article/vote/<id>` is being matched  by this url pattern:

```
url(r'^ironfaq/(?P<topic_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<section_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="faq-article-detail"),
```

Since detail views only handle get requests, your post request causes a 405 response.

You either need to redesign your url patterns so that they don't clash, or move the `faq-article-detail` url pattern below the vote url pattern (and any others that it clashes with).